# Can revving the engine cause damage to the fuel pump?

Tags: engine, starting, dodge, ram, fuel-pump

I have a 2009 Dodge Ram 1500 and someone was revving my engine while they had the vehicle in park. The vehicle broke down on them losing all power to the engine not too long after. I’ve had some people look at it and say it’s the fuel pump. That there’s no noise when trying to start it coming from the fuel pump. I’m just curious if there’s a way to damage the fuel pump by over revving the engine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You or others must have superb hearing because fuel pumps (electric ones in fuel tanks) don't make loud noise. You can use a diy stethoscope,  screwdriver blade pressed to fuel tank, handle pressed to ear and listening. Some, like myself, can hear the faint hum/hiss sounds of the pump running for a few seconds at ignition on time before starting. A fuel pressure gauge  or depressing the fuel test valve after ignition is turned on to see if fuel and pressure sprays out with force. This presumes '09 uses an electric fuel pump in EFI. A dead pump won't generate any pressure (between 35-60 psi).

Comment: @FDryer - Not sure what you're saying about pumps, because the ones I've dealt with I have no problem hearing and my hearing isn't good to start with. For instance, my truck (2018 Silverado) fires the pump when I open the driver's door. I can hear it plain as day. Not that it's loud, but it is distinctive.

Comment: I'm a member of  one car forum and many members cannot hear their fuel pump running. Every model is EFI.

Comment: Dodge things, lol.  You did manage to discover the only thing revving an engine is good for.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no, revving the engine will not cause damage to the fuel pump. The fuel pump is engineered from the factory to be able to provide the engine with as much fuel as it needs. Revving the engine, even to redline, shouldn't cause the fuel pump any issues.